# Signalr setup on kubernetes

Tags: signalr

i want to setup signalr on Kubernetes, i am not getting any tutorial to setup signalr on kube.

if any one knows or have any link how to setup signalr on Kubernetes please give me that is more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With Kubernetes you typically expose your webapp via an "Ingress" controller like NGINX.

Take a look at the NGINX section of the official hosting documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-6.0